# iCloud Document Picker with Custom UTI

Tags: ios, ios8, icloud, uti, icloud-drive

Does `UIDocumentPickerViewController initWithDocumentTypes` require a public UTI to function?

I am trying to utilize iCloud Documents to allow users to import a proprietary file type from iCloud Drive. Testing works fine for public UTI, such as: `@"public.text"`

If I don't include a public UTI in the `initWithDocumentTypes` array, I get a screen indicating:

> No Documents. Documents in iCloud Drive are not available because the
>   iCloud Documents & Data setting is disabled.

My Imported UTI is defined in Target > Info as "com.domain.file". I have to believe this is set up correctly, as I can select one of my proprietary files in another app (e.g. Dropbox) and my app is displayed in the Open In... options.

In my import action, I've tried every variation I can think of to get my custom UTI to display the picker.

```
- (IBAction)importDocumentPickerTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"com.domain.file", @"com.domain.app.file", @"iCloud.com.domain.file", @"iCloud.com.domain.app.file" ] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
    documentPicker.delegate = self;
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If I add `@"public.text"` to the `initWithDocumentTypes` array, then the iCloud Drive Locations picker screen displays as expected. I can select .txt and .rtf files, but my custom file types are grayed out and not selectable.

Note:

1. I have not created a Document Provider extension, as I don't believe this is required, and my file format it not common.
2. I see the following warning when I take any action on `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, even if it's Cancel and even if the action on a file (i.e. save .txt) works. I've spent quite a bit of time just trying to track down the source of this warning, to no avail.

> plugin com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default invalidated

Comment: Having the same issue exactly. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and addressed it by having my custom exported UTI conform to the 'public.data' UTI.

You can set this by selecting your target and then the info tab.  Scroll to the Exported UTIs section and expand it.  Under your custom UTI there is a box to declare that it conforms.

See here for a list of system defined UTIs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. What an absolute hodgepodge of API Apple has slapped together. Complete hit-and-miss, with no proper warning. Everything is grayed out in the FilePicker. I've tried adjusting every possible setting in the custom UTI.